# Proof of surjectivity of this function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am asked to prove the surjectivity of the function $f: \mathbb{N_0^2} \to \mathbb{N}, f(n,m)=2^n(2m+1)$ where $\mathbb{N_0}=\mathbb{N} \cup 0$

I have: let $n=0$ and $m=\frac{b-1}{2}$.

$f(n,m)=2^n(2m+1)=(2m+1)=2(\frac{b-1}{2})+1=b$. I conclude for every $b\in \mathbb{N}$ that there exists a $(m,n)\in \mathbb{N_0^2}$. Hence,  $f$ is indeed surjective. However, my answer file has a totally different outcome. Hence, I was wondering whether my proof was correct or not. Could anyone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: nope. not fine.

Comment: You need to be careful. $\frac{b - 1}{2}$ may not be a natural number; it could be just a fraction.

Comment: $(n,m)=\left(\upsilon_2(b),\frac{\frac{b}{2^{\upsilon_2(b)}}-1}{2}\right)$, where $\upsilon_2(b)$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that $m = \frac{b-1}{2} \in \mathbb N$?

If $b$ is an even number then your argument fails.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, didn't think about that. Will try another solution

Comment: The good news however - You successfully proved that any odd number has a source wrt to $f(n,m)$. So now you just need to focus on even numbers.